# Implementing React on RoR project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to implement React on a RoR project. I added a frontend folder in my project directory and created a component file index.jsx, but it's not showing the changes I applied to the Rails view with React when I tested it with Rails server. Here's what I have in my Rails view:

`<main id="root"></main>`

And in my React frontend folder I have an index.jsx with below code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const root = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Welcome to my page</h1>, root);
});
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is simply add a h1 tag to the root element, but I only see an empty main tag with id root when I inspected the page.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0gYx.png)

Not sure if this helps but here's my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./frontend/index.jsx",
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app", "assets", "javascripts"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
            presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
            },
        },
        },
    ],
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", "*"],
    },
};
```

I tried to add something directly in my Rails view and it works just fine, so I think I can assume it's a frontend problem.

```
<main id="root">
    <h1>Test Rails</h1>
</main>
```

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akPEr.png)

This is my view code that loads html, basically the default code for any rails new project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Intro-Me</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if any information is needed. I appreciate any help on this :)

Comment: Could you check the javascript console for any errors reported and add them to the question?

Comment: Also, it would be good to include the view code that loads the assets in the html, and also the rails version (assets are handled differently in different rails version)...

Comment: @GarrettMotzner thanks for replying, the error message says
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map

Comment: @GarrettMotzner I also added the view code with assets

Comment: Well, the "failed to load source map" error is apparently hiding the real error. (Source maps are for debugging only, and generally don't break code). Can you tell chrome to ignore source maps and then see what the errors are, or are there other errors   besides the source map errors?

Comment: I unchecked the source map option and now there's no error message

Comment: Hmmm... is chrome saying `bundle.js` was loaded on the page? (Maybe add a `console.log` toward the top of your index.jsx page and see if that runs...)

Comment: That's how I debugged earlier, and it didn't even hit the debugger... would it be an issue in my webpack config?

Comment: Did you use 'react_on_rails' or a similar Ruby Gem to first integrate React into your Rails application? Due to the Rails pipeline and asset bundling, I have found it easiest to use the 'react_on_rails' gem to get everything setup correctly so that React works well with Rails and its Asset Pipeline. Also, what version of Ruby and Rails are you using?

Comment: Yep, looks like the problem is not your javascript, but rather how you are loading your javascript. Looks like it isn't being loaded.

Comment: This tutorial may help: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-rails-project-with-a-react-and-redux-front-end-8b01e17a1db/ (Not sure what rails version it is targeting though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'll just answer my own question, and the issue is in my `webpack.config.js`. I didn't realize the directories and files in app folder are different now. When I was using Rails 5.2.4 this

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app", "assets", "javascripts"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
},
```

would work, when I had the script tag in `application.html.erb` as

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

, but now they change it to

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

in new version, whose route is /app/javascript/packs so now the output in webpack.config.js should be

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app", "javascript", "packs"),
    filename: "application.js",
},
```

This solved my problem.